# Getting error while run project with oracle database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle11g

I am using EF5 and DOT.NET framework 4.5, install ODEC to connect database oracle 11g in windows 10 professional. now while i run the project getting the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.EntityException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: The underlying provider failed on Open

Comment: my error is: An exception of type 'System.Data.EntityException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open.

Answer (score 0):

Have you go through this tutorial? https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm